# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'app.firestore')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I just started learning React Native and while watching a video on youtube, I encountered an error that I did not understand. I think my error is caused by the firebase.js file.`

firebase.js

```
import * as firebase from "firebase"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/auth"


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

let app

if (firebase.apps.length === 0){
    const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
} else {
    app = firebase.app()
}

const db = app.firestore()
const auth = firebase.auth()

export { db, auth }
```

error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'app.firestore')
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

video = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJzmZ9qmdaE&t=7s
video time is 1:10:39

Comment: I think `const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` should be  `app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you, its work

Answer (score 7):

Try this in your config

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBbBFNGMI",
  authDomain: "sixxxxxxxxxcc8.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "sxxxxxxxxxxx8",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxcc8.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "6xxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "1:65xxxxxxxx13:web:d0exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7c"
};

let app;

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
} else {
  app = firebase.app();
}

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

Comment: 3 days of debugging an ionic app brought me here and that solved it for me. Upvoting and commenting so hopefully somebody else gets help as well.  Tags:

ionic, capacitor, ios, cors, undefined is not an object when gapi.client.init()