# `Firebase` package was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to read and write to firestore, use firebase's authentication, and firebase's storage within a expo managed react-native application.

Full Error:

```
While trying to resolve module `firebase` from file `C:\Users\joshu\Desktop\VSProjects\VolleyballConnect\firebase.js`, the package `C:\Users\joshu\Desktop\VSProjects\VolleyballConnect\node_modules\firebase\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\joshu\Desktop\VSProjects\VolleyballConnect\node_modules\firebase\index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * C:\Users\joshu\Desktop\VSProjects\VolleyballConnect\node_modules\firebase\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * C:\Users\joshu\Desktop\VSProjects\VolleyballConnect\node_modules\firebase\index\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
```

My firebase config file:

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/storage";

// I'm using the example key here, I have the correct config
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "api-key",
  authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "project-id",
  storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
  appId: "app-id",
  measurementId: "G-measurement-id",
};

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { db, auth, storage };
```

I installed the `firebase` package with:

```
expo install firebase
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To reduce the size of the app, firebase SDK (v9.0.0) became modular. You can no longer do the import statement like before on v8.

You have two options.

1. Use the backwards compatible way. (it will be later removed):

This:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Should be changed to:

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

2. Refactor your code now.

From this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

const auth = firebase.auth();
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => { 
  // Check for user status
});
```

To this:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
  // Check for user status
});
```

You should definitely check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

Answer (score 15):

I have met the same issue today, in my case, it has been solved by followings.

1.

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

2. 

change from ↓

```
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

to ↓

```
app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

[This link was really helpfull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879378/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-app-firestore)

To ba safe, I share my firebase.js (hiding personal info)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBbBFNGMI",
  authDomain: "sixxxxxxxxxcc8.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "sxxxxxxxxxxx8",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxcc8.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "6xxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "1:65xxxxxxxx13:web:d0exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7c"
};

let app;

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
} else {
  app = firebase.app();
}

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

Answer (score 5):

Uninistall firebase, then install firebase@8.2.3

Answer (score 2):

First check your package.json , what is your firebase version.

```
"firebase": "9.9.1",
```

if it is more than 9.0.0 you can change it to

```
"firebase": "8.2.3",
```

and run

```
npm install
```

it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

After alot of research i found that we have not configured metro to read .cjs extensions.

create a metro.config.js file in root folder and paste this code.

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: [...assetExts, "cjs"],
    },
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this import statement in **firebase.js file**

```
import  firebase  from 'firebase/compat';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when my project was named "firebase".

Simply renaming the project and editing the name in the package.json fixed this for me.