# React native Expo || Firebase integration || Errors

Tags: react-native

Im trying to integrate Firebase with my React native Expo project. But, It throws a strange error something like this. Really no idea about What went wrong.

Installed it using : expo install firebase

Expo : 43.0.2 || Firebase : 9.8.0. Thanks in advance.

```
 While trying to resolve module `firebase` from file 
`D:\PROJDIR\src\Config\Firebase.js`, the package 
`D:\PROJDIR\node_modules\firebase\package.json` was successfully found. 
However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved 
(`D:\PROJDIR\node_modules\firebase\index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`Firebase\` package was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a \`main\` module field that could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69814654/firebase-package-was-successfully-found-however-this-package-itself-specifie)

Comment: No, I have tried that before posting a question. That's not helping.